# Topological space, continuous function, and closed set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological sets, $f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous for every $n$. Let $X_k=\{x\in X : |f_{p_n}(x)-f_{p_m}(x)|\leq\varepsilon_{p_n}+\varepsilon_{p_m} \text{ for every } m,n\geq k\}$ such that $\bigcup X_k = X$ and $X_1\subset X_2\subset ...$ Prove that $X_k$ is closed for every $k$.

This problem is based on work by P. Das, Sudipta Dutta and Sudip Kumar Pal. Precisely, theorem 3.2 of "On $I$ and $I^*$-equal convergence and an egoroff-type theorem.

This paper saud that "it is clear that $X_k$ is continuous since $f_n$ is continuous and $X_1\subset X_2\subset ...$.

I just learned topology myself for proving this theorem, but I still dont get it. Can anyone please tell me? I'm dying for help here lol. At least give me some hint. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are those $p_n$, $p_m$, $\epsilon_{p_n}$, etc?

Comment: What do you know about premises of closed sets under continuous maps?